# Why is a curly brace around a string not outputting the correct SimpleXML result?

Tags: php, xml, oop, simplexml, curly-braces

I am getting data from an API that returns a list of tasks like so:

```
<tasks>
  <task>
    <id type="integer">937510</id>
    <external-id nil="true">
      <description>needs to be italic in the 2nd line of copy in this paragraph</description>
    </external-id>
  </task>
</tasks>
```

I am attempting to parse the above XML using this simple PHP code in 5.6.2. `$api` is an object of a previously defined class that retrieves data without issue:

```
$tasks_xml = $api->get_project_tasks('17347');
$tasks_object = new SimpleXMLElement($tasks_xml);
echo '<h2>'.$tasks_object->task[0]->id.'</h2>';
echo '<h2>'.$tasks_object->task[0]->{'external-id'}->description.'</h2>';
```

However, the output I receive is the following. `external-id` is not accessed even though I am surrounding it in curly braces and quotes.

```
<h2>280095</h2>
<h2></h2>
```

I get the same result if I save `'external-id'` to a variable like `$external_id` and access it using `->task[0]->$external_id`.

What do I need to do to access the data inside the `external-id` node?

Edit: it turns out that when SimpleXml parsed the XML, it made `description` a child of `external-id`. Updating the query to `task[0]->description` solved the problem. Thanks, mario.

Comment: What's the representation in `$tasks_object`? (print_r)

Comment: I've just tried with you sample XML and it displays correctly. In your output the ID value is different. Are you sure that the description is not empty?

Comment: That ID is a project ID, not a task ID. For some reason, simplexml is parsing description as a sibling and not a child of external-id. I'm not sure why this is happening, but changing my query fixed the problem.

Comment: This worked fine for me. http://codepad.viper-7.com/QxBp9v

Comment: Interesting - must be an artifact of the actual dataset of tasks that causes the deviant behavior in the conversion.